# conflicting cases in python lists

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I have two lists of sets -

`attribute = [{0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7}, {4, 5}]`

and

`decision = [{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}, {6, 7}]`

I want -

`{3, 4}`

Here, `{3, 4}` is conflicting, as it is neither a subset of `{0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7}`, nor of `{4, 5}`.

My code -

```
 check = []
 for i in attribute:
      for j in decision:
          if j.issubset(i):
              check.append(j)
 print(check)

 for x in decision:
     if not x in check:
         temp = x

 print(temp)
```

This gives me `{3, 4}`, but is there any easier (and/ or) faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension:

```
[d for d in decision if not any(d <= a for a in attribute)]
```

This returns:

```
[{3, 4}]
```

If you want just the first set that satisfies the criteria, you can use `next` with a generator expression instead:

```
next(d for d in decision if not any(d <= a for a in attribute))
```

This returns:

```
{3, 4}
```

Comment: thanks @blhsing. But I assume it will take some more time to convert it from `[{3, 4}]` to `{3, 4}`

Comment: But there could be more than one set in the `decision` list that is not a subset of any of of the sets in the `attribute` list. Returning just `{3, 4}` makes little sense unless you are guaranteed that there is always exactly one such set that satisfies your criteria. That said, I've updated my answer with a solution that would return what you want, as long as you are sure that you only want the first matching set, or there is always only one matching set.

Comment: @blhsing This makes more sense to me, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [i for i in decision if not [j for j in attribute if i.issubset(j)]]
```

result is the list of all set they are not a subset of attribute. :)

This is the compact version of :

```
result = []
for i in decision:
    tmp_list = []
    for j in attribute:
        if i.issubset(j):
            tmp_list.append(j)
    if not tmp_list:
        result.append(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried  `result = [i for i in decision if not [j for j in attribute if i.issubset(j)]]` which gives me `[{3, 4}]`, but not `{3,4}` (I know the conversion is possible). But is it faster than my solution (with additional conversion time)?

Comment: EDIT : sorry, my last calcul was wrong, our program has same execution time after convertion on my computer : 0.030 - 0.050 sec

Comment: Thanks @ iElden i upvoted, but @blhsing's explanation makes more sense to me.